# phpacademy tutorial Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, pdo

Good day. I am following phpacademy's tutorial about login/registration system. everything is being followed but i still get errors regarding foreach. Does this have something to do with the versions or whatsoever? Ive seen the same questions but I can't seem to comprehend with the answers so please excuse me for duplication. I will delete this immediately if this is being a nuisance. This is the code by the way.

```
public function query($sql, $params=array()){
    $this->_error=false;
    if($this->_query=$this->_pdo->prepare($sql)){
        $x=1;
        if(count($params)){
            foreach($params as $param){ //the error is here
                $this->_query->bindValue($x,$param);
                $x++;
            }
        }
        if($this->_query->execute()){
            $this->_results=$this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
        }else {
            $this->_error=true;
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Thank You. :)

Comment: `var_dump($params)` to debug it. I am guessing that `$params` as you passed it to the `query()` function is a _string_, and not an array.  `count()` will return `1` when called on a string so the guard condition `if (count($params))` will succeed.

Comment: ohh... yeah it is a string. so how am i gonna change it? i mean how to make it an array? thanks

Comment: That depends on how you are calling the function... If you did `$something->query($sql, $your_string_param)` and it is known to be a string, you can force it to an array by wrapping it `$something->query($sql, array($your_string_param))`  But if it is already an array that will cause you problems.

Comment: it's rather a question WHY you are supplying a string where array is expected

Comment: If you post the code where you define the variable and call the `query()` method, we can help you fix the problem at its source.

Comment: Please provide a minimum example, containing also the creation and usage of an object of the class, whose code you provided.

Comment: it was minimum a while ago... okay i will edit it again. thanks

Comment: It was always less than minimal because it was unclear where `$params` got its value. Don't read this as an attack. It is just a comment to help you submit better questions in the future. If we don't know how `$params` gets its value, then we can only make assumptions about why you're receiving errors. Luckily, this time, @MichaelBerkowski made the right assumption.

Comment: I don't consider that as an attack. I'm learning from you guys. thanks

Comment: so i got it working. the problem is on the other file. my index.php which has this code 

$user=dbase::getInstance()->get('user',array('username','=','alex'));

is supposed to be


$user=dbase::getInstance()->query('user',array('username','=','alex'));

-:)